# FOR XML PATH Performance Improvement challenge

Tags: sql-server, view, query-performance, correlated-subquery, for-xml-path

I'm working on improving view performance that uses 20 columns with the FOR XML PATH('') function. The view also calls other fields using nonclustered Views CTEs, Subqueries and CAST function but I'm not concerned about them at this point.

The view is a nonclustered view and is being selected every 5 minutes by a job to display the fresh data to the client application. So underlying source tables are being updated and inserted every 5 minutes a well.

I've created clustered and nonclusterd indexes everywhere where it is appropriate. Tested individual view components on the source tables before corresponding indexes were created and after and chose the best rout. So, I did a good job on indexing. Fill factor values is 100 pretty much on all indexes.

My assumption is that the query is slowing down a lot because I'm using FOR XML PATH ('') on 20 columns in view...

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS 
col1,
Col2,
(SELECT CAST(Mytbl.[EmpId] AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '|' FROM MyDB.dbo.Mytbl_Optimized AS t1 (NOLOCK) 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN AnotherDB.dbo.Another-tbl AS t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON t1.EmpId = t2.EmpId 
WHERE AnotherDB.dbo.Table3.MyId = t1.MyId
FOR XML PATH('')) AS MyConcatenatedID
FROM AnotherDB.dbo.Table3
```

I tried using a CASE statement that determines if each columns with the FOR XML PATH('') anything to concatenate on a row by row basis and then use FOR XML PATH('') only when is's has 2 or more values to concatenate to a string. But the performance as I expected was terrible...

```
,CASE
        WHEN 
            (SELECT
                LEN(EmpId) - LEN(REPLACE(EmpId, '|', '')) AS [CountOfConcatinated_EmpId] 
            FROM ISSearch..SearchBid WITH (NOLOCK)
            ) > 1  -- this determis if values are concatenated or not. 
        THEN 
            (SELECT CAST(Mytbl.[EmpId] AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '|' FROM MyDB.dbo.Mytbl_Optimized AS t1 (NOLOCK) 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN AnotherDB.dbo.Another-tbl AS t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON t1.EmpId = t2.EmpId 
                WHERE AnotherDB.dbo.Table3.MyId = t1.MyId
        FOR XML PATH(''))

        ELSE
            (SELECT CAST(Mytbl.[EmpId] AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '|' FROM MyDB.dbo.Mytbl_Optimized AS t1 (NOLOCK) 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN AnotherDB.dbo.Another-tbl AS t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON t1.EmpId = t2.EmpId 
                WHERE AnotherDB.dbo.Table3.MyId = t1.MyId)
        END AS EmpId 
FROM AnotherDB.dbo.MyView;
```

I'm now considering option of caching already concatenated by the FOR XML PATH('') function strings of all 20 columns as separate column on the view, but it needs to be constantly updated (every 5 minutes).

Any ideas or alternative solutions?

Comment: I'm assuming `AnotherDB.dbo.Another-tbl as t2` is a dummy name, but do those need to be left joins (or there at all)? At least in the provided query, they don't seem to be doing anything. A couple other things I'd like to know: 1) how many rows are being concatenated into each value for `MyConcatednatedId` 2) how many rows are in `Table3` 3) How slow is it performing now 4) how fast do you need it?

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Answer (score 0):

Vague questions get vague answers, but here goes.

I agree it's seems likely all the `FOR XML` concatenation is probably contributing (and certainly without seeing an execution plan or your full database schema, pretty much the only thing I have to go on). There are a lot of unknowns here which might change the advice. If you can include your query plan(s) and IO statistics, that would help.

I also don't claim to know specifically why or if you need to use a view or concatenate values at run time, but some here are some exploratory questions:

1. How many rows are in `dbo.Table3` (the base table against which you're concatenating values?
2. How many rows are being concatenated into each `MyConcatenatedId` value?
3. How slow is it performing now, and how fast does it need to be?
4. Roughly how many reads per minute/second is this view getting?
5. `dbo.another-tbl` doesn't appear to be doing anything in the subqueries provided (maybe it does in the real version). Do you need that? Does it need to be a left join?

My initial thought is if this needs to be performant and isn't, don't use a view. If you must use a view, maybe play around with index hints like [NOEXPAND](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/indexed-views-and-statistics) What alternatives do you have?

**Don't Serialize**: I'm having difficulty picturing a scenario where high-volume data needs to be serialized at run-time. If possible, return sets of data or serialize the data when it's put in.

- Pros

  - Easy on the DB side
- Cons

  - Might not be possible for what you need to do

**Persisted Table/Do Work Ahead of Time**: Probably would need triggers too, but when the underlying data changes, write it to a persisted table, and read from that. Or queue up changes in something like [Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx), then work of those changes asynchronously

- Pros

  - Fast to read from
- Cons

  - Pain to maintain and triggers could add onerous overhead

**Procedures**: Unless you need all that data for every call, consider making a procedure which can be parameterized to pull only the stuff you need when you need it. A view is limited to a single query, and the statistics on a query of that complexity might quickly become garbage. A procedure could separate out statements individually and in smaller chunks so you get a consistent and faster plan more often.

- Pros

  - Much more customizable than a view and more optimization things you can do
- Cons

  - Can't directly query them (although I don't think that's a good reason not to use them)

Comment: You *could* query a stored procedure with (potentially nested?) openquery shenanigans :D